# How can I view when a reminder was set in Adobe Sign?

Tags: adobe-sign

I have a form that I need other people to sign in Adobe Sign. A while ago, I configured a weekly reminder to be sent to the other people to remind them to sign the form. How can I view when a reminder was set in Adobe Sign?

I don't see the information when I click on the reminder:

[image]